# How to get the position of all the player in Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I want to know how to get the position of all available player in the network.
So how can I update my script ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Pathfinding : MonoBehaviour {
Transform[] Players;
int TotalPlayerCount=0;
void Update() {
    foreach (PhotonPlayer pl in PhotonNetwork.playerList) {
        if (GetComponent<PhotonView> ().isMine) {
            Players[TotalPlayerCount].position= //position of my player
            TotalPlayerCount++;
        } 
        else
        {
            Players[TotalPlayerCount].position=//position of all other player available in the room
            TotalPlayerCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each client can set it's player's custom properties with SetCustomProperties, even before being in a room. They are synced when joining a room.

```
Hashtable xyPos = new Hashtable();
xyPos.Add(1, "10");
xyPos.Add(2, "-20");
PhotonPlayer.SetCustomProperties(xyPos, null, true) ;
```

For further reading, you should try following tutorial(It will give you a stronger idea how to get and sync positions): 
http://doc.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/tutorials/tutorial-marco-polo#_Toc317517599